# Changing controls of compound control at run time

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls

I have inflated xml in my custom compound control.

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout{
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_views, null));
            }
    }
```

I have included this compound control in 4 different layouts. One of layouts:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/wall1Layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wall1withkey" >

  <com.example.room.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/customView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
....
</RelativeLayout>
```

All the 4 layouts I've included into viewflipper:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/water_room_flipper"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <include layout="@layout/water_room_wall1" android:id="@+id/first" />
    <include layout="@layout/water_room_wall2" android:id="@+id/second" />
    <include layout="@layout/water_room_wall3" android:id="@+id/third" />
    <include layout="@layout/water_room_wall4" android:id="@+id/fourth" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

Then I have changed some controls of this compound control at run time in a method in the mainactivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.water_room_view_flipper);
    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.water_room_flipper);
        vf.setDisplayedChild(R.id.first);
}

    ...

   public void someOnClickMethod(){
    ...
   RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.customView);  
   ImageButton newItem = (ImageButton)rl.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);//this is  inside common_view.xml which was inflated in CustomView class(compound countrol)
   newItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.key_stored);
         }
```

As you can see someOnClickMethod changes background image of one of the controls. But it doesn't take effect in other 3 layouts, only in the first one. How can I change control so that it takes effect in all of the layouts the compound control included in?